# CQ5/JSP how to load content of folder

Tags: java, jsp, directory, aem

how can I load content of a folder in Adobe CQ5/JSP? I've tried this code

```java
File folder = new File(pathToFolder);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
if(listOfFiles == null){    //this statement is just for debugging purposes
    System.out.println("NULL");
}else{
    System.out.println("NOT NULL");
...
```

but I'm still getting the NULL output from println().

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Since you are trying to do it in a JSP can you show the actual JSP code? What happens if you debug your code? Is folder being resolved?

Comment: @Jeroen I've found where the problem is... It looks like I can't load the folder - if i do folder.exists(); it returns false. I've tried to change the path to "." and it works. So the problem is, how can I load CQ5 folder if I only have relative path(for example /content/folder/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you making a assumption that folders in the CRX repository can be treated the same as folders on the file system, which of course, is wrong, and leads to the problem.

I'd suggest using the Sling API, and using [ResourceResolver](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html) to get a reference to your folder and get it's child resources from there.  Possibly, depending on exactly what you are trying to do, you might consider using the JCR Node API.  There are also CQ specific API's for working with DAM Assets, Pages, etc. and the proper API depends on what you're trying to do, so without knowing that, I can't make a specific reccomendation.

Answer (score 0):

```
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = request.getResourceResolver();
Resource rootResource = resourceResolver.getResource("/apps/yourapp/somelocation");
Resource chileNode = rootResource .getChild("some/child/relative/path");
Map<String, Object> valueMap = new CaseInsensitiveMap(chileNode.adaptTo(ValueMap.class));
--get valueMap values....
```